# Getting list data as string in java

Tags: java

I have a list of data in the iterator.I want to store it in a string. How can I do it? Here is my code.

```
List ln = readData(iStepNumber, status, query);

Iterator itr = ln.iterator();

System.out.println("listttt"+ln);

while(itr.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println("itr value1 :"+itr.next());
    //what to do to store itr.next() in a string
    //for example String a=itr.next()?
}
```

This is what I get in the console

```
listttt[2017-06-30 23:59:59]
itr value1 :2017-06-30 23:59:59
```

Comment: Use a StringBuilder or StringBuffer to build your string together, if you need all the items in your list in the same string

Comment: You should specify which kind of string you are expecting. `String.join(",", ln)` might be what you're looking for, but then I don't see what's wrong with your current output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just implement `toString()` method in your object and output the list using `System.out.println(list)`. This will display all the data without any need of iteration manually in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of just printing `itr.next()`, save it to a string variable like this:

`String yourString = itr.next();`

If you have more than one item in the list, you can either do `yourString += itr.next()`, or use a `StringBuilder` and `StringBuilder.append()`, which is much more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You should use stringbuffer

```
List ln = readData(iStepNumber, status, query);
Iterator itr = ln.iterator();
System.out.println("listttt"+ln);

StringBuffer sBuffer = new StringBuffer();

while(itr.hasNext()){
  sBuffer.append(itr.next());
  System.out.println("itr value1 :"+itr.next());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java 8 stream API.
Take your list of respective object type

```
List<Object> ln = readData(iStepNumber, status, query);
Iterator itr = ln.iterator();
System.out.println("listttt"+ln);

// Now call the stream() method on list 

 String data=ln.stream()  
               .map(Object::toString)  
               .collect(Collectors.joining(","));

// Here use whatever you want as string in joining method string and print 
// or do what ever you want with string data.

System.out.println(data);
```